# Short url for my domain name using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create a custom url for my domain.

for example i want url like this:- mysite.com/ERJDII787HUKKS

Instead of :- mysite.com/index.php?args=ERJDII787HUKKS

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^$ /index.php/$1 [L]

But its not working well please help!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below rule in your root directory

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)$ index.php?args=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, Its Working :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex you are using is empty, so it can't match any URL you are trying to access. And you should rewrite it you your real URL. Try using this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?args=$1 [L]
```

I hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Did you allow rewrite on your apache configuration? If yes, can you give more information about the problem?

Comment: Yes, mod_rewrite is allow. on your code rewrite rule not working with direct domain.com/SOME-ARGUMENT